# Why are there explosions everywhere?

Tags: bastion

Sometimes when I'm playing Bastion there are small explosions on the map. Not necessarily near me, or near any enemy. What's happening? Am I being shelled?

Comment: A screenshot may help.

Comment: Do you have any idols turned on?  I know there's an idol that makes enemies drop grenades when you kill them and they weren't that easy for me to see all the time so it looked like random explosions.

Comment: Yes! I've seen grenades drop. That must be it.

Comment: @MCeley You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the Acobi idol turned on then enemies will drop live grenades when you kill them.  The grenades weren't very easy for me to see all the time so it looked like random explosions.

http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Acobi

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that one, good call.